Puedo crear un entorno virtual de python 3 en python 2.7?
si no es mucha molestia quisiera saber si es posible crear un entorno virtual de python 3.11.
El contexto es que tengo una pequeña tarea de crear un clúster y para ello estoy usando Rocks Linux el SO que este usa es CentOs ,el cual tiene python 2.7, pero para hacer correr un software necesito Node.js (React) y Python 3.11 para algunas librerías. Quisiera saber si fuera posible hacer correr el software y de ser posible. Como puedo crear el env, ya he buscado y solo hallo crear envs de python2 con python 3. Muchas gracias por tomarse la molestia de leer mi problema.

yum install -y python3

Lo mejor sería instalar Python 3. Puedes tener múltiples versiones de Python en la misma máquina.

En general, mucho cuidado con actualizar/modificar la instalacion de Python del sistema en Linux fuera de las actualizaciones normales del gestor de paquetes si no se sabe lo que se hace muy bien, muchas cosas del propio sistema operativo dependen de el y no son pocos los casos de terminar incluso con un sistema o DE incapaz de arrancar por rotura de dependencias con el interprete Python o algunos de sus paquetes. Si el SO tiene 2.7 como base generalmente no es problema instalar 3.x, pero por norma general hay mejores alternativas y más flexibles.

Hay multiples opciones, como usar contenedores, distrobox, etc pero lo más simple en general es pyenv, con ello es trivial instalar cuantas versiones quieras de Python, incluidas multiles implementaciones (CPython,  jython, PyPy, anaconda, miniconda, etc) mientras se deja intacta la instalación intérprete del SO, pudiendo cambiar la version a usar en cada shell, globalmente, por directorio, etc. Puedes instalar 3.11 con $ pyenv install 3.11 y luego crear el VENV con el mismo pyenv o con el módulo venv de Python: $ pyenv shell 3.11 && python -m venv venv

En GNU/Linux puedes tener Python3.11 y Python2 al mismo tiempo, al instalar Python3 mediante apt-get install python3 en distribuciones basadas en Debian puedes crear el entorno con python3 -m venv NombreDeTuEntorno
Sin embargo, el procedimiento para instalarlo depende de la distribución especifica con la que trabajas. En caso de que este método no funcione, siempre puedes instalarlo manualmente siguiendo la documentación.
